# Python Avoid Nested For Loop

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, nested

I am new to python programming and I am getting my hands dirty by working on a pet project.

I have tried a lot to avoid these nested for loops, but no success.

[Avoiding nested for loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11174745/avoiding-nested-for-loops)

[Returns values from a for loop in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5135211/returns-values-from-a-for-loop-in-python)

```
import requests
import json

r = requests.get('https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/')
j = r.json()


for item in j:
    item['id']
    n = item['id']
    url = 'https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/%s' %n
    req = requests.get(url)
    js = req.json()
    for cool in js:
        print n
        print cool['rank']
```

Please let me know if more information is needed.

Comment: Sometimes you need nested for loops. This looks like one of those times.

Comment: I am getting a lot of data and having nested for loop is too time consuming :( I understand your point though. Thank you for the feedback.

Comment: To avoid writing a nested loop, you could create a function to parse `js` that contains the inner for loop. Note that this would still technically contain nested loops, but your code will at least appear flatter.

Comment: @Master The reason of getting rid of nested for-loop is usually to make it more readable or easier to maintain. It will seldom improve speed.

Comment: @Master Are you requesting the same `url` repeatedly? It looks like the only way to reduce complexity/time would be to reduce the number of requests. If each request is unique, I'm not sure how you could do that.

Comment: @JaredGoguen yes, I am appending the url with values I get and requesting the new appended url to get actual data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first request already gets you everything you need.

```
import requests
import json

response = requests.get('https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/')
coin_data = response.json()

for coin in coin_data:
    print coin['id'] # "bitcoin", "ethereum", ...
    print coin['rank'] # "1", "2", ...
    print coin['price_usd'] # "2834.75", "276.495", ...
```

Comment: Respect. Appreciate the response.

Answer (score 1):

## Question

I have too many loops in loops and want a **python** way of cleaning it up

## Answer

Yes, there is a python way of cleaning up loops-in-loops to make it look better but there will still be loops-in-loops under-the-covers.

```
import requests
import json

r = requests.get('https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/')
j = r.json()

id_list = [item['id'] for item in j]

for n in id_list:
    url = 'https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/%s' %n
    req = requests.get(url)
    js = req.json()
    print "\n".join([ n+"\n"+item['rank'] for item in js ])
```

## Insight from running this

After running this **specific** code, I realize that your are actually first retrieving the list of tickers **in order of rank** using

```
r = requests.get('https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/')
```

and then using

```
url = 'https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/%s' %n
```

to get the rank.

So long as the **https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/** continues to return the items in order of rank you could simplify your code like so

```
import requests
import json

r = requests.get('https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/')
j = r.json()

id_list = [item['id'] for item in j]

result = zip(id_list,range(1,len(id_list)+1) )

for item in result :
print item[0]
print item[1]
```

## Answer to addition question

**Addition question** : *What if I want one more parameter say price_usd? ..... for cool in js: print n print cool['rank'] print cool['price_usd']*

**Answer** :

change the line

```
print "\n".join([ n+"\n"+item['rank'] for item in js ])
```

to

```
print "\n".join([ n+"\n"+item['rank']+"\n"+cool['price_usd'] for item in js ])
```

Comment: What if I want one more parameter say price_usd?
.....
        for cool in js:
            print cool['price_usd']

Comment: I updated the response to have the additional answer.

Comment: thank you for the input and explaining a pythonic way to write a code :)

Comment: don't say thanks, just upvote and/or accept the answer.  cheers

Comment: Well I can't upvote because my reputation is too low. Also, Jared Goguen's response saves me a lot of execution time :) But, I appreciate your efforts to help me out.